# How to safely abort chkdsk?

Tags: external-hard-drive, chkdsk

I am running chkdsk on a 1TB external hard drive. The scan is at stage 5 (scanning free space). It is taking forever... Is there a safe way to abort this? The drive has less than 20GB worth of stuff on it.

Comment: ctrl+c works for me.

Comment: It works, but is it safe? And besides, I tried it and it DID NOT work.

Comment: I've never had any trouble with it. Now, of course, one cannot prove it is safe ... since one cannot prove that someone somewhere didn't once had some trouble with it ... but for me, it is *safe enough*.

Comment: I don't recall ctrl+c ever successfully canceling chkdsk.  I've always had to close the console (if running in a console) or reboot (if running a boot-time scan).  Are you sure you're not thinking of Scandisk from back in the day?

Comment: sorry guys, i was thinking about fsck...

Comment: ctrl+c closes chkdsk for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, I've never had any trouble closing the CMD prompt.  If you scheduled a boot-time scan, you're probably safe rebooting since you're just working with the free space right now, but then chkdsk will not have scanned the free space for bad blocks.